# How to derive these calculus identities?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The following are calculus identities, but I never memorized them and don't know how to derive them: 
$$ \cos(\mathbf{n},x_1) = \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}}{\pm \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\right)^2}} \\ 
\cos(\mathbf{n},x_2) = \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}}{\pm \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\right)^2}} \\ 
\cos(\mathbf{n},x_3) = \frac{1}{\mp \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\right)^2}}, $$ where $ x_3 = f(x_1,x_2)$ is the equation of a surface $S$, $\mathbf{n}$ is the unit exterior normal to $S$, and $\cos(\mathbf{n},x_i)$ denotes the cosine of the angle between $\mathbf{n}$ and the $i$th-axis of the rectangular coordinate system.

Comment: And what are $f,\ {\bf n}$?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Why is cosine written as a function of two arguments?

Comment: $\cos(\mathbf{n},x_i)$ denotes the cosine of the angle between the unit exterior normal $\mathbf{n}$ and the $i$th-axis of the rectangular coordinate system.

Comment: @fctaylor25 It would be great if you put that in your question.

Comment: @Potato: No problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gradient vector to the function $x_3 - f(x_1, x_2)$ is $\left[-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, -\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}, 1\right]$.  This  is normal to the surface.  So you divide by the length $\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\right)^2}$ to get a unit normal.  Its dot product with a unit vector (in particular the unit vector in the coordinate direction $[1,0,0]$, $[0,1,0]$ or $[0,0,1]$) is the cosine of the angle between those vectors.

Comment: Why is the gradient vector to $x_3 - f(x_1,x_2)$ normal to the surface?

Comment: Essentially because the linear approximation dominates near the point in question, and this is true for a linear function.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use $\vec{F}(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2,f(x_1,x_2))$, which is a two-parameter family of points which lie on the given surface. Any partial derivative of $\vec{F}$ must be tangent to the surface. A normal to the surface is then obtained by crossing two tangent vectors:
$$
     \frac{\partial \vec{F}}{\partial x_1}\times\frac{\partial \vec{F}}{\partial x_2}
    = (1,0,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1})\times (0,1,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2})
    = \left|\begin{matrix}\hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z}\\ 1 & 0 & f_{x_1} \\ 0 & 1 & f_{x_2}\end{matrix}\right|=(-f_{x_1},-f_{x_2},1).
$$
(If these partials are not linearly-independent, then the surface parametrization has a vanishing Jacobian, and no other such crossed vector gives anything better.) Normalizing gives the desired unit surface normal, which is unique up to a scale of $\pm 1$.